# Show logging for a vbs script

Tags: vbscript, uninstallation

I have a script i use for uninstalling an application

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Product " _
      & "Where Name = 'Personnel database'")
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
  Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objSoftware.Name
  Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objSoftware.Version
    objSoftware.Uninstall()
Next
```

The problem is i don't know if the

1. Has started running or has completed
2. uninstall has completed
3. Has completed

Is there a way to show this in a log file or a console.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall has completed when [`Uninstall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393941) returns with return code 0. Having your script log something is entirely up to you, though. You could write stuff to a log file or the eventlog, show a `MsgBox` or write text to the console (when running with `cscript.exe`).

A while ago I wrote [this](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/clogger.shtml) to simplify the handling (if you'll forgive the shameless plug). You could use it like this:

```
'insert class code here

Set clog = New CLogger
clog.LogToConsole = False
clog.LogFile = "C:\path\to\your.log"
clog.IncludeTimestamp = True

clog.Log "Starting"

'...

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
  clog.Log "Uninstalling " & objSoftware.Name & " (v" & objSoftware.Version & ")"
  rc = objSoftware.Uninstall()
  If rc = 0 Then
    clog.Log "Uninstall complete"
  Else
    clog.LogError "An error occurred: " & rc
  End If
Next
clog.Log "Finished"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always put msgbox in your script in your for each loop

```
  MsgBox("Uninstalling " + objSoftware.Name)
```

or you could do a simple in your for each loop

```
  Wscript.Echo "Uninstalling " + objSoftware.Name
```

Just run your vbs from admin command prompt window open

```
   wscript uninstallfile.vbs
```

This will show up in your command console.

Comment: Hi.. Assume the for loop runs only once.. i need something that monitors the uninstall process itself. Eg. i ran the script and i did not have any idea that the uninstall actually ran and completed.

Comment: oh lol. you're going to need a more advanced language than vbscript. You want to monitor progress of the uninstall. You may need to dig into the msi/install, and extract variables. In some more advanced languages you can hijack the hwnd window of the invisible uninstall and retrieve variables of the form (eg progress percentage). It's far too convoluted for what you want to do. You can also check to see if msiexec is running, and if their is a process called msiexec running then it's still uninstalling. That only works for msi's and windows based installs though.